# C# DateTime object + stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm calling a stored procedure from my code using `SqlCommand`, some of the parameters are of `DateTime` type, when calling the procedure from Management Studio I use the following format `yyyy-MM-dd` for example `2011-01-01`, and results are returned accordingly.

In my C# code I'm creating the `DateTime` object like the following:

```
DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2011,01,01);
```

and when I run the application the dates are being complete ignored and all the data is being returned. After the debugging accordingly I'm noticing that the format of the `DateTime` object is being: `{01/01/2011 00:00:00}` so probably this is causing the issue.

The parameters are being added to `SqlCommand` like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Any idea please?

Copying code:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
    DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2011,01,01);
        DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(2011, 01, 31);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strStoredProcName, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime);

    cmd.Parameters["@DateFrom"].Value = dateFrom;
        cmd.Parameters["@DateTo"].Value = dateTo;
 }
```

Comment: The `DATETIME` doesn't have any string representation - it's a 8-byte binary datatype. Can you show us the signature of the stored procedure you're calling? And the **whole code** of how you're calling it from C# ?

Comment: Is your field in the database actually a `DATETIME`?

Comment: Show your SQL code, it is probably either (a) not using the right data type or (b) not using the parameter correctly. Also it is important to know what the data type of the column is...

Comment: this is my code: using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
 DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2011,01,01);
        DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(2011, 01, 31);

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strStoredProcName, conn);
 cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 
 cmd.Parameters["@DateFrom"].Value = dateFrom;
        cmd.Parameters["@DateTo"].Value = dateTo;
 }

Comment: is it your full code ?

Comment: Please don't post code as a comment. And can you answer the questions you haven't answered yet? What does your stored procedure look like? What is the data type of the column? I am fairly confident the problem isn't on the C# side. So please show us the details we're asking for on the database side. As an edit to the question, not an unreadable comment.

Comment: Also, given the use of `DateTime` and the specific values chosen, I'm a little afraid you're going for an inclusive end-date.  Please review [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for the perils of this approach (and some specific issues SQL Server has).

Answer (score 3):

There should be no format issue from C# to SQL for date time data type.

There may be 2 things causing this issue:

1. As far I can remember, you not need to add @ for the parameter name

   `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);`
2. The overload of AddWithValue is string parameterName and object value. You have passed SqlDbType.DateTime as the value. Pass your DateTime variable instead.

Comment: It seems there is something in your sql procedure. Can you show it to us?

Answer (score 3):

you have two options either choose `Add` or `AddWithValue` with following format:

1) `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom;`

2)  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dateFrom);`

Answer (score 0):

If the datetime parameter in stored procedure is type of DateTime, you need not to essentially pass the value as datetime. You can pass simple string value like below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "23-03-2013";
```